# NetLogo: "with" command with multiple criteria

Tags: syntax, netlogo

I want to use the "with" command to select turtles that are matching two criteria, X and Y. I don't know how to include the second criteria (Y) into the first bracket.

It looks like this:

ask other turtles with [X = 1 and Y=1] [

The "and" command is probably not the way to go, just so you understand what I am trying to achieve.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you try it with `and`?  Did you find any problems?  (It will work.)

Comment: Yes, I did and it did not work. Now I tried again and now it works. I don't know what to say, except thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the first time you left out space around the equal signs.  Glad its working for you now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that should work...

this code works:

```
ask patches with [pycor <= 1 and pxcor > 7] [ set pcolor 23]
```

sometimes netlogo has random compile issues, I'd try running it again or reopening your editor.